# How to wait for fetch to complete before running another function

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am currently trying to create a map with markers on it and I would like some of the markers to be represented by a different icon if a user has previously indicated that this marker is one of their "favourites".

To do this I am trying to use a function that fetches first and then pushes part of the data into an array and I am then using another function to create a map and populate it with markers. I would like this second function run only after the first function has complete. Unfortunately every time I run the code all the markers are the same and it seems that the array which should contain the ID of all the favourite stops is empty. I think this means that the await is not working correctly as the first function has not finished running.

The code is:

```
var favouriteStops = []

async function firstFunction(){
    fetch("api/favstop/")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
    for(var i = 0; i<= data.length; i++){
        favouriteStops.push(data[i].stopid)
     }
 })
};


function addFavStop (){
        console.log(favouriteStops)
    }

async function initMap(){

    await firstFunction();
    //Map options
    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat:53.3477, lng:-6.2800},
        styles: mapStyle,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    }

    //Creating the map 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);


    //Add marker function
    function addMarker(stop){

        var coords = {lat: stop.lat, lng: stop.long}
        //Style for the icon
        if (favouriteStops.includes(stop.id)){
            var icon = {
                url: '../static/images/favourite.png',
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(12, 12)
            };
        } else {
            var icon = {
                url: '../static/images/bus-stop.png',
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(12, 12)
            };
            console.log(favouriteStops, stop.id)
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map:map,
            icon: icon,
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            name:stop.name,
            id:stop.id
        })

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: marker.name + '<br>' + '<button htmlType="submit" onClick=addFavStop()> Add Stop As Favourite </button>'
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function(){
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

    }

    //Adding markers for each stop
    for(var i = 0;i < stops_import.length;i++){
        addMarker(stops_import[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `async` functions need to **return** a promise, so just add `return` before `fetch` in `firstFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

For `await` to actually wait until `fetch` is done, you should return the promise:

```
async function firstFunction(){
  return fetch("api/favstop/")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    for(var i = 0; i<= data.length; i++){
      favouriteStops.push(data[i].stopid)
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: When I change the firstFunction to this the map fails to load. In the console I get an error stating: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopid' of undefined"

Comment: That's a different problem. Likely because you have only the stopid in the array and not the whole stop items, but the code you posted doesn't tell us what the `stops_import` actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily resolve this issue by using `await` inside `firstFunction` like:

```
async function firstFunction() {
  const response = await fetch("api/favstop/")
  const data = await response.json();
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    favouriteStops.push(data[i].stopid)
  }
};
```

Or, just return the promise like:

```
async function firstFunction() {
  return fetch("api/favstop/")
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        favouriteStops.push(data[i].stopid)
      }
    })
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked for me. In both cases the map fails to load. In the console I get an error stating: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopid' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the promise chain within an async function. In fact, it kinda defeats the whole purpose. So, your async function would look kinda like this:

```
async function firstFunction(){
   const fetcher = await fetch("api/favstop/");
   const data = await fetcher.json();
   
   for(var i = 0; i<= data.length; i++){
      favouriteStops.push(data[i].stopid)
   }
};
```

Comment: When I change the first function to this I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'stopid' of undefined"